# Opening Same Modal Window from different Components and communicating exact parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Modal Window component as below:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

class ModalWindow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false,
        }
    }
    show() {
        this.setState({
            showModal: true,
        })
    }
    hide() {
        this.setState({
            showModal: true,
        })
    }

render() {
    return (
        <ReactBootstrap.Modal
            show={this.state.showModal}
            container={this.props.container}
            bsSize='small'>
            <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header closeButton={true} >
                <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title" >
                    Login
                </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>
            </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>
            <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body >
                Login Here
            </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
        </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
    );
 }
}
export default ModalWindow
```

And then I have 3 different components A,B, C as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ModalWindow from './ModalWindow';

class A extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        };
    }

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    };

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({ showModal: false });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>You are in A</h1>
                <ModalWindow show={this.state.showModal} container={this} />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.showModal}>
                    open
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    };
}    
export default A

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ModalWindow from './ModalWindow';

class B extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        };
    }

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    };

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({ showModal: false });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>You are in B</h1>
                <ModalWindow show={this.state.showModal} container={this} />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.showModal}>
                    open
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}    
export default B

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ModalWindow from './ModalWindow';

class C extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        };
    }

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    };

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({ showModal: false });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>You are in C</h1>
                <ModalWindow show={this.state.showModal} container={this} />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.showModal}>
                    open
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}    
export default C
```

And I have component called X as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
import C from './C';

class X extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React Modal</h1>
                <A />
                <B />
                <C />
            </div >
        );
    }      
}
export default X
```

The class X is being called in the Menu, but when I load the X, it shows only open button for 3 times for 3 components A,B,C but it is not opening the Modal Window. What I want is I want to open the Modal Window and the Modal Window to have the information of the which components Open button is clicked and I want to have a TextBox and a Dropdown in the Modal Window and I want to pass the information of the modal window to the same parent Component that has opened the modal window - any help please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
import C from './C';
import ModalWindow from './ModalWindow';

class X extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        };
    }

    handleChange = (val) => {
      this.setState({
         showModal: val
      })
    }    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React Modal</h1>
                <A showModal={this.handleChange} />
                <B showModal={this.handleChange} />
                <C showModal={this.handleChange} />
                <ModalWindow show={this.state.showModal} />
            </div >
        );
    }      
}
export default X
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

class ModalWindow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({
        showModal: this.props.show
      })
    }

    componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
      if(nextProps.show != this.props.show){
         this.setState({
           showModal: nextProps.show
          })
      }
    }
    show() {
        this.setState({
            showModal: true,
        })
    }
    hide() {
        this.setState({
            showModal: true,
        })
    }

render() {
    return (
        <ReactBootstrap.Modal
            show={this.state.showModal}
            container={this.props.container}
            bsSize='small'>
            <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header closeButton={true} >
                <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title" >
                    Login
                </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>
            </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>
            <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body >
                Login Here
            </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
        </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
    );
 }
}
export default ModalWindow
```

---

```
class A extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }

    changeModalState = (val) => {
        this.props.onChange(val)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>You are in A</h1>

                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.showModal(true)}>
                    open
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.showModal(false)}>
                    CLOSE
                </button>
            </div>
        );
}
export default A
```

Comment: Hi I a getting the following error when I tried above code, any help please? ×
TypeError: this.props.showModal is not a function
onClick
C:/Users/aaleem/Desktop/DevelopedProjects/ReactDevExtremeExample/DropdownListBoxEx/ClientApp/src/components/DialogModals/A.jsx:21
  18 |            <div>
  19 |                <h1>You are in A</h1>
  20 | 
> 21 |                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.showModal(true)}>
     | ^  22 |                    open
  23 |                </button>
  24 |                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.showModal(false)}>

Comment: My bad , I made a typo.
Now I have corrected "ModalWindow" Class.
It should fix this error